# Do you provide a screen reader api for visually impaired person in codename one?

Tags: android, codenameone

In my app I want more facility of screen reader app that is useful to visually impared person means they heard button click and document. 
so their is any api provided that which helpful to make app more flexible?

Answer (score 1):

It's called accessibility and it should be mostly "seamless" for application developers. We have an [RFE](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/426) for integrating that and it's technically very doable. Unfortunately it's not trivial so we didn't accomplish it in the 3.8 timeframe and I'm not sure about the 4.0 timeframe either.

It's a very important task and we'd like to do it. Notice this is a something you might be able to accomplish/implement as a pull request as it's an external tool to the implementation that maps the OS native accessibility API's to Codename One's `Component` hierarchy.