# how do I use android provided talkback facility in codename one using as native code?

Tags: android, codenameone

Android provided talkback facility for android mobile to useful for visually impaired person.

how we can write native code if user click on that option to activate this facility. so we can redirect them on setting like End-users of Android 1.6 (Donut) can enable TalkBack, SoundBack and KickBack via the Accessibility section of the Settings menu.

so we redirect user on setting menu in android mobile. I want to implement it using Native Android code in Codename one.

Comment: How is this question different from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47974747/do-you-provide-a-screen-reader-api-for-visually-impaired-person-in-codename-one